# For each observation in one data frame, count number of observations in a second data frame

Tags: r, count, conditional-statements

I have two data frames. I would like to run on all of the observations from the first one, and add a column indicating the number of observations from the second data frame that fit a certain condition.

For example:

```
DF1                               
observation Value              
1            3
2            5
3            8
4            10
5            1

DF2                               
observation Value              
1            8
2            9
3            2
4            1
5            3
```

I want to create a third column for DF1, indicating the number of observations in DF2 that have a value (for example) that is at most greater or smaller by 2 (|Value2 - Value1| <= 2). Thus my result would be in this case:

```
DF1                               
observation Value  Count              
1            3       3
2            5       1
3            8       2
4            10      2
5            1       3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can loop over the 'Value' of 'DF1', get the `sum` of the absolute difference of it will be the 'Value' from 'DF2' that is less than or equal to 2

```
DF1$Count <- sapply(DF1$Value, function(x) sum(abs(x-DF2$Value) <=2))
```

---

Or with `outer`, we get the difference of each of the combinations of the 'Value' columns from the datasets, check whether the absolute value is less than or equal to 2 and find the `rowSums`

```
DF1$Count <- rowSums(abs(outer(DF1$Value, DF2$Value, `-`))<=2)
DF1$Count
#[1] 3 1 2 2 3
```

Comment: Thanks! This seems to get what I needed.

Comment: For those who want to check, i add the input code:

observation = c(1:5)
Value = c(3,5,8,10,1)
DF1 = data.frame(observation,Value)

observation = c(1:5)
Value = c(8,9,2,1,3)
DF2 = data.frame(observation,Value)