# Count number of observations in one data frame based on values from another data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, count, aggregate

I have two very large data frames(50 million and 1.5 million) where some of the variables in both are same. I need to compare both and add another column in one data frame which gives count of matching observations in the other data frame.

For example: DF1 and DF2 both contain id, date, age_grp and gender variables. I want to add another column (match_count) in DF1 which show the count where DF1.id = DF2.id and DF1.date = DF2.date and DF1.age_grp = DF2.age_grp and DF1.gender = DF2.gender
Note

**DF1**

```
id  date    age_grp gender  val
101 20140110    1   1       666
102 20150310    2   2       777
103 20160901    3   1       444
104 20160903    4   1       555
105 20010910    5   1       888
```

**DF2**

```
id  date    age_grp gender  state
101 20140110    1   1        10
101 20140110    1   1        12
101 20140110    1   2        22
102 20150310    2   2        33
```

In the above example the combination "id = 101, date = 20140110, age_grp = 1, gender = 1" appears twice in DF2, hence the count 2 and the combination "id = 102, date = 20150010, age_grp = 2, gender = 2" appears once,hence the count 1.

Below is the resultant data frame I am looking for

**Result**

```
id  date    age_grp gender  val match_count
101 20140110    1   1       666  2
102 20150310    2   2       777  1
103 20160901    3   1       444  0
104 20160903    4   1       555  0
105 20010910    5   1       888  0
```

Here is what I am doing at the moment and it works perfectly well for small data but does not scale well for large data. For this instance it did not return any results even after several hours.

Note: I have gone through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42696854/for-each-observation-in-one-data-frame-count-number-of-observations-in-a-second) thread and it does not address the scale issue

```
with(DF1
     , mapply(
        function(arg_id,arg_agegrp, arg_gender, arg_date){
            sum(arg_id == DF2$id
                & agegrp == DF2$agegrp
                & gender_bool == DF2$gender
                & arg_date == DF2$date)
          },
    id, agegrp, gender, date)
)
```

**UPDATE**

The Id column is not unique, hence there could be two observations where id, date, agegrp and sex could be same and only val column could be different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is what I will solve this problem by using `dplyr`

```
df2$state=NULL#noted you do not need column state
Name=names(df2)
df2=df2%>%group_by_(.dots=names(df2))%>%dplyr::summarise(match_count=n())
Target=merge(df1,df2,by.x=Name,by.y=Name,all.x=T)
Target[is.na(Target)]=0

Target
   id     date age_grp gender val match_count
1 101 20140110       1      1 666           2
2 102 20150310       2      2 777           1
3 103 20160901       3      1 444           0
4 104 20160903       4      1 555           0
5 105 20010910       5      1 888           0
```

Comment: I think the logic is the way to go, but why not go full dplyr and use `left_join` instead of `merge`?

Comment: @thelatemail I just get used to merge ..But you are right , I should change the `merge` to `join`

Answer (score 3):

`data.table` might be helpful here too. Aggregate `DF2` by the variables specified, then join this back to `DF1`.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DF1)
setDT(DF2)

vars <- c("id","date","age_grp","gender")
DF1[DF2[, .N, by=vars], count := N, on=vars]
DF1

#    id     date age_grp gender val count
#1: 101 20140110       1      1 666     2
#2: 102 20150310       2      2 777     1
#3: 103 20160901       3      1 444    NA
#4: 104 20160903       4      1 555    NA
#5: 105 20010910       5      1 888    NA
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. Please see the update. The problem with the solution is that if there are several observations having same id, date,agegrp, gender and date column then the count appears against every combination. So observation `101 20140110       1      1 666` and `101 20140110       1      1 999` both are going to have count equal to 2. Please suggest